# Scrape multi page URL using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to scrape multi page URL using BeautifulSoup,

I'm trying to scrape webpage but I'm stuck, any idea will be helpful

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from pathlib import Path
import os.path
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from tldextract import extract
# URL of the web page you want to extract
url = "https://www.taneps.go.tz/epps/viewAllAwardedContracts.do?d-3998960-p=1&selectedItem=viewAllAwardedContracts.do&T01_ps=100"

# initialize a session
session = requests.Session()
# set the User-agent as a regular browser
session.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"

# get the HTML content
html = session.get(url).content

# parse HTML using beautiful soup
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: What is your code doing differently from what you want your code to do?

Comment: I'm stuck, I want to scrape all pages of that website

Comment: There is a page variable in the link before selected item  `-p=1&selectedItem`. Use a for loop through changing this `p=1` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to go through all the pages

```py
# import urllib.parse

url = "https://www.taneps.go.tz/epps/viewAllAwardedContracts.do?d-3998960-p=1&selectedItem=viewAllAwardedContracts.do&T01_ps=100"

session = requests.Session()
session.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"

i = 0 
while url:
    html = session.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    
    #######  EXTRACT AND SAVE THE DATA YOU WANT  #######

    nxtBtn = soup.select_one('button.SearchBtn[title="Next"][href]')
    if nxtBtn:
        url = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, nxtBtn.get('href'))
        print('going to next page', url)
    else: url = None
```

`nxtBtn` gets the tag for the button that takes the user to the next page; as long as that can be found, the `href` is extracted from the tag to update `url` and continue to the next iteration - once it can't be found, `url` is set to `None` so that the `while` condition is no longer upheld and the loop terminates.