# cannot scrape ratings

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My issue is that I cannot use bs4 to scrape sub ratings in its reviews.
[Below is an example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQYUR.png)

So far, I have discovered where these stars are, but their codes are the same regardless of the color (i.e., green or grey)... **I need to be able to identify the color to identify the ratings, not just scrape the stars.** Below is my code:

```
url='https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Walmart-Reviews-E715_P2.htm?filter.iso3Language=eng'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
com = soup.find(class_ = "ratingNumber mr-xsm")
com1 = soup.find(class_ = "gdReview")
com1_1 = com1.find(class_ = "content")
```

Comment: `com` gets you the rating as a number - why do you need the star colors after that?

Comment: @Jaevapple- I do understand better now (You should specify in your question that you want the *sub*ratings as well, since the immediately visible ratings have a numeric value as well, so star colors are not important.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the star rating breakdown (which seems to have no numeric display or meta value), I don't think there's any very simple-and-straight-forward short method since it's done [by css in a `style` tag connected by a class of the container element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pATGa.png).

You could use something like `soup.select('style:-soup-contains(".css-1nuumx7")')` [ the `css-1nuumx7` part is specific to rating mentioned above], but [`:-soup-contains`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains) needs [`html5lib`](https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/) parser and can be a bit slow, so it's better to figure out the `data-emotion-css` attribute of the `style` tag instead:

```py
def getDECstars(starCont, mSoup, outOf=5,  isv=False):
    classList = starCont.get('class', [])
    if type(classList) != list: classList = [classList]
    classList = [str(c) for c in classList if str(c).startswith('css-')] 
    if not classList: 
        if isv: print('Stars container has no "css-" class')
        return None
    
    demc = classList[0].replace('css-', '', 1)
    demc_sel = f'style[data-emotion-css="{demc}"]'
    cssStyle = mSoup.select_one(demc_sel)
    if not cssStyle:
        if isv: print(f'Nothing found with selector {demc_sel}')
        return None
    
    cssStyle = cssStyle.get_text()
    errMsg = ''
    if '90deg,#0caa41 ' not in cssStyle: errMsg += 'No #0caa41'
    if '%' not in cssStyle.split('90deg,#0caa41 ', 1)[-1][:20]: 
        errMsg += ' No %'
    if not errMsg:
        rPerc = cssStyle.split('90deg,#0caa41 ', 1)[-1]
        rPerc = rPerc.split('%')[0]
        try:  
            rPerc = float(rPerc)
            if 0 <= rPerc <= 100:
                if type(outOf) == int and outOf > 0: rPerc = (rPerc/100)*outOf
                return float(f'{float(rPerc):.3}')
            errMsg = f'{demc_sel} --> "{rPerc}" is out of range'
        except: errMsg = f'{demc_sel} --> cannot convert to float "{rPerc}"' 
    if isv: print(f'{demc_sel} --> unexpected format {errMsg}')
    return None
```

**OR**, if you don't care so much about why there's a missing rating:

```py
def getDECstars(starCont, mSoup, outOf=5, isv=False):
    try:
        demc = [c for c in starCont.get('class', []) if c[:4]=='css-'][0].replace('css-', '', 1)
        demc_sel = f'style[data-emotion-css="{demc}"]'
        rPerc = float(mSoup.select_one(demc_sel).get_text().split('90deg,#0caa41 ', 1)[1].split('%')[0])
        return float(f'{(rPerc/100)*outOf if type(outOf) == int and outOf > 0 else rPerc:.3}')
    except: return None
```

---

Here's an example of how you might use it:

```py
pcCon = 'div.px-std:has(h2 > a.reviewLink) + div.px-std'
pcDiv = f'{pcCon} div.v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__fullWidth'
refDict = {
    'rating_num': 'span.ratingNumber',
    'emp_status': 'div:has(> div > span.ratingNumber) + span',
    'header': 'h2 > a.reviewLink',
    'subheader': 'h2:has(> a.reviewLink) + span',
    'pros': f'{pcDiv}:first-of-type > p.pb',
    'cons': f'{pcDiv}:nth-of-type(2) > p.pb'
}

subRatSel = 'div:has(> .ratingNumber) ~ aside ul > li:has(div ~ div)'
empRevs = []
for r in soup.select('li[id^="empReview_"]'):
    rDet = {'reviewId': r.get('id')}
    for sr in r.select(subRatSel):
        k = sr.select_one('div:first-of-type').get_text(' ').strip()
        sval = getDECstars(sr.select_one('div:nth-of-type(2)'), soup)
        rDet[f'[rating] {k}'] = sval
    
    for k, sel in refDict.items():
        sval = r.select_one(sel)
        if sval: sval = sval.get_text(' ').strip()
        rDet[k] = sval
    
    empRevs.append(rDet)
```

If `empRevs` is viewed as a table:

| reviewId | [rating] Work/Life Balance | [rating] Culture & Values | [rating] Diversity & Inclusion | [rating] Career Opportunities | [rating] Compensation and Benefits | [rating] Senior Management | rating_num | emp_status | header | subheader | pros | cons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| empReview_71400593 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 3 |  | great pay but bit of obnoxious enviornment | Nov 26, 2022 - Sales Associate/Cashier in Bensalem, PA | -Walmart's fair pay policy is ... | -some locations wont build emp... |
| empReview_70963705 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | Former Employee | Walmart Employees Trained Thrown to the Wolves | Nov 10, 2022 - Data Entry | Getting a snack at break was e... | I worked at Walmart for a very... |
| empReview_71415031 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | Current Employee, more than 1 year | Work | Nov 27, 2022 - Warehouse Associate in Springfield, GA | The money there is good during... | It can get stressful at times ... |
| empReview_69136451 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 4 | Current Employee | Walmart | Sep 16, 2022 - Sales Associate/Cashier | I'm a EXPERIENCED WORKER. I ✨... | In my opinion I believe that W... |
| empReview_71398525 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | Current Employee | Depends heavily on your team | Nov 26, 2022 - Personal Digital Shopper | I have a generally excellent t... | Generally, departments are sho... |
| empReview_71227029 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | Former Employee, less than 1 year | Managers are treated like a slave. | Nov 19, 2022 - Auto Care Center Manager (ACCM) in Cottonwood, AZ | Great if you like working with... | you only get to work in your a... |
| empReview_71329467 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 1 | Current Employee, more than 3 years | No more values | Nov 23, 2022 - GM Coach in Houston, TX | Pay compare to other retails a... | Walmart is not a bad company t... |
| empReview_71512609 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | Former Employee | Walmart midnight stocker | Nov 30, 2022 - Midnight Stocker in Taylor, MI | 2 paid 15 min breaks and 1 hou... | Honestly nothing that I can th... |
| empReview_70585957 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | Former Employee | Lots of Opportunity | Oct 28, 2022 - Human Resources People Lead | Plenty of opportunities if one... | As with any job, management is... |
| empReview_71519435 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 5 | Current Employee, more than 3 years | Lot of work but worth it | Nov 30, 2022 - People Lead | I enjoy making associates live... | Sometimes an overwhelming amou... |

> <sub>Markdown for the table above was printed with pandas:</sub>
>
> ```py
> erdf = pandas.DataFrame(empRevs).set_index('reviewId')
> erdf['pros'] = [p[:30] + '...' if len(p) > 33 else p for p in erdf['pros']]
> erdf['cons'] = [p[:30] + '...' if len(p) > 33 else p for p in erdf['cons']]
> print(erdf.to_markdown())
> ```

Comment: Could not thank you even more! This is ABSOLUTELY the answer I am looking for. I will learn your code by heart. It looks very awesome to me, and I will google to learn it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jaevapple I'd be glad to help as much as I can, but I'm afraid I can't see any edits to your q and I don't quite understand what you mean by *"each review has the same total number of reviews"*... you can find number of pages by splitting the text from `soup.select_one('div[data-test="pagination-footer-text"]')` [ [at the bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPqBX.png) ], and the next page link from the `href` of `soup.select_one('li:has(a.page.selected) + li a.page[href]')` [ see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74334463/6146136) for an example of how to scrape paginated results ]

Comment: @Jaevapple I saw the bit in your q about missing 4-part sub-ratings. I've added updated version[s] of `getDECstars` at [https://pastebin.com/Q0GLwRv9](https://pastebin.com/Q0GLwRv9) (new/changed lines are marked with `## edit`), and that should take care of that particular issue

Comment: @Jaevapple but the problem remains of the `requests` failures... you could easily use selenium by replacing your `extract(pg)` function with [something like this](https://pastebin.com/VLZ2vPYK), but it appears that some of the needed `style` tags  disappear after the page loads so *none* of the sub-ratings might show